# joining 2 lines based on first field

Tags: linux

Hi i have something like this in a file

```
12345   aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb 
23456   bbcbcbbgyhuhuhhhhhhh 
12345   7ijkunmmnniiiiiiii
23456   bbcbcbbgyhuhsdrfrrhhhv
```

I want to merge lines into a single line based on first

field i,e.,

```
12345   aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb 12345   7ijkunmmnniiiiiiii
23456 bbcbcbbgyhuhuhhhhhhv 23456   bbcbcbbgyhuhsdrfrrhh
```

can any one let me know how to do that?

Comment: sed 'N;s/\n/ /' is joining the lines but i couldnt get how to specify my condition

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;

open my $fh, '<your_file'
   or die "cant open file $!";

my %result; # result hash

# read file line by line
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;

    # check format
    if ( $line =~ m/^(\d+)\s+(.*?)$/x ) {

        # add value to anonymous array in hash
        $result{$1} = [] unless exists $result{$1};
        push @{$result{$1}}, $2;
    }
}

# print result
while (my ($key, $values) = each %result) {

   printf "%s ", $key;
   for my $value (@$values) {

       printf "%s,", $value;
   }
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: hi, its printing just 3rd and 4rth lines of my file its not merging the lines having common first field

Comment: Sorry, I have mistake in regexp, I've already fixed it. Try again :)

Comment: hi thank you very much ts working i wanted the result to be printed line by line

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<DATA>) {
    ($x, $y) = split;
    push @{$lines{$x}}, $y;
}

while (($x, $y) = each %lines) {
    print "$x\t$_\t" for @{$y};
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
12345   aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb 
23456   bbcbcbbgyhuhuhhhhhhh 
12345   7ijkunmmnniiiiiiii
23456   bbcbcbbgyhuhsdrfrrhhhv
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` alternative:

```
awk '
  { A[$1] = A[$1] $0 " " } 
  END { for (k in A) print A[k] }' infile
```

Concatenates each line on to an associative array with `$1` as the key.